# What is the best way of creating a list of querysets in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model class "Place", which has a field for "state", and I would like to get a list of querysets  grouped by all available distinct states in the DB.

I am currently doing this:

```
place_list = []
places = Place.objects.distinct('state')
[place_list.append( Place.objects.filter(state=p.state) ) for p in places]
```

Is there a better aggregate command I could use for optimizing this? What would be the best way to do this?

~ using Python 2.6, Django 1.3.1

Comment: If you are planning on displaying these at the template level, you could use the `regroup` tag : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

Comment: Thanks pastylegs!! This is useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

places_by_state = defaultdict(list)
for place in Place.objects.all():
   places_by_state[place.state].append(place)
list_of_places_by_state = places_by_state.values()
```

That only hits the database once, rather than once per state like your original version (assuming you use all the results), but you end up with a list of lists instead of a list of querysets.

Comment: *What is the best way of creating a list of querysets in django?* I don't see the **list of querysets** here ...

Comment: @julio.alegria Good point -- now there's a list of lists. If you do actually want queryset objects instead of lists, your / [istrubble's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9027755/344821) is of course the right way.

Comment: I think you should change it to `places_by_state[place.state].append(place)`

Comment: Thanks @Dougal.  I still like your answer for showing a way to reduce DB hits.  Our answers optimize things a little differently.

Comment: Actually this made more sense to me, since the DB gets hit once, even though the output required some minor changes in views.

Comment: @priyeshj careful not to optimize early.  Readability and maintainability count for a great deal.  Go with what is easiest to understand until you learn that you need to be a bit more performant.

Answer (score 3):

How about you get just the values for the states ([`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) is a handy tool here):

```
states = Place.objects.values_list('state', flat=True).distinct()
```

and then do what you were doing for each state but use the results of your [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  and skip the .append() call.

```
place_list = [Place.objects.filter(state=state) for state in states]
```

This still hits the DB count of states + 1 times but you are only performing the query for the states right at the start.  The QuerySet objects in `place_list` will still be lazy and not get evaluated until you use them.

NOTE: the comment by @pastylegs about using the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag in your template may be the most insightful thing any of us has said.  My answer is really just showing you about `value_list` and list comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks istruble! This worked for me. regroup is also a really handy tool from the looks of it

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the list comprehension correctly. A list comprehension is not for repeating actions, it's for creating lists. So this what I would do:

```
places = Place.objects.distinct('state')
place_list = [Place.objects.filter(state=p.state) for p in places]
```

That's just the same you did before, but I'm just using the list comprehension correctly.