# Group records in queryset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following models in an django app.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like to get a list of orders placed by a buyer grouped according to the owner of the product in the order.

Something like this

```
orders placed by buyer 1
    order__product__owner 1
        order 1
        order 2
        order 3
    order__product__owner 2
        order 4
        order 5
        order 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9027725) you can do this with a little extra logic in Python, carefully constructed to use only a single database query:

```
buyer = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
grouped_orders = {}
for o in buyer.order_set.all():
    grouped_orders.setdefault(o.product.owner, []).append(o)
```